# iOS 7 colorWithAlphaComponent error

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I am trying to have my button's border change color when pressed and I'm finding some issues. This is what I have:

```
UIColor *blackColor;
UIColor *transBlack = [blackColor colorWithAlphaComponent:05f];
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor transBlack].CGColor;
```

Now the last line is giving me an error which reads **"No known class method for selector 'transBlack' "** and **"Property 'CGColor' not found on object of type 'id' "** I have no idea what either of these mean. I'd like to get that last line to work, and if you could explain to me why the compiler is complaining that would be very helpful.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
So I tried using a different method

```
colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness: 0 alpha: 0.5
```

and that seems to have broken my button's push outlet. I'm not sure why yet.

**Edit2:**

This seemed to correct the original issue of using colorWithAlphaComponent

```
UIColor *transBlack = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
self.layer.borderColor = transBlack.CGColor;
```

for more information please look at the selected answer.

Comment: So I used 'colorWithHue' instead and that seems to give me the effect that I was looking for. For some reason using 'colorWithAlphaComponent' made my button not able to click.

Comment: is self the UIButton?

Comment: Yes, this is under a custom button class that extends UIButton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems that I can see. First you are creating a variable "blackColor" but are not assigning anything to it (so it will be nil). I think what you meant was to call the class method `blackColor` on UIColor (allocates and initializes a UIColor instance). The second problem is `[UIColor transBlack]`. There is no selector on UIColor called transBlack. You just created a variable called transBlack which happens to be an instance of UIColor... So just get the CGColor from transBlack directly.

Something like this:

```
UIColor *transBlack = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
self.layer.borderColor = transBlack.CGColor;
```

Comment: YES! But I think you meant to but '0.5' and not 5.0. 0.5 gives it half alpha.

Comment: Why the 'f' at the end?

Comment: So it works but it broke my push outlet, any ideas why? Do I need to put something else under `touchesEnded:withEvent` ?

Comment: Also, the text no longer changes to half alpha when you press the button. Any ideas why?

Comment: The reason for the f is that it forces the number to be a 32 bit float (as apposed to a double). Have you tried hooking the button to an IBAction? You shouldn't need to do anything with touchesEnded to get your button to work..